# Run cron job in CodeIgniter and Hostgator

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run the follow cron job in codeigniter and hostgator

```
/usr/bin/php /home/username/public_html/index.php cronjob contact martin
```

But nothing happens, I receive the following email:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index:  REMOTE_ADDR</p>
<p>Filename: core/Input.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 351</p>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/iglesias/public_html/mysite.com/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 675</p>
```

My controller is as follows (simply sending an email to test).

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cronjob extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->cron();
}

function cron()
{
    if(!$this->input->is_cli_request())
    {               
        die();
    }
}

function contact($name)
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('test@gmail.com', $name);
    $this->email->to('test2@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('test');
    $this->email->message('test sent');             
    $this->email->send();
}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would really appreciate your help.

I changed the .htaccess to remove the index.php when called from URL, I don't know if this has something to do.

Thanks

Comment: I just want to confirm that you are able to run a CodeIgniter page using CLI from a cron job.  How did you get an email with the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you setup the correct route in config/routes.php? Try running the script from your browser (or commenting out the execution part) to make sure it's accessible with your current route/htaccess setup.

Comment: I have run the script from the browser and it runs normally.

Comment: I fixed it with wget and url

Comment: please share example to set routes and htaccess setup.

Answer (score 14):

my answer comes a long time after, but it could help other people.
This error is apparently well known, but there is only a quick fix for it : http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/227672/
It says that it happens when you autoload session library, it calls CI_Input::ip_address() which is not initialized or something like that. 
The quick fix is in the input class (core/Input.php Line 351 (CI 2.1.2)) :

```
$this->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

become :

```
if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
   $this->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
   $this->ip_address = '0.0.0.0';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to confirm that this is still the case on version 2.1.4.  And the fix works!

Comment: Yes indeed. CI changed the whole forum and I cannot find the post again. That's why I put the quick fix directly in my post, so it is not lost even if the source is not available.

Comment: Well, here's the whole post about the bug on GitHub: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1890

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Hostgator is running Apache as Fast-CGI instead of module.  If that is the case, the run path to PHP may be different from what you are using.

You might see the relevant information if you check phpinfo.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by @mariek

But we can also do this by just using `@` sign before the syntax.

So Just made a little change in "core/Input.php" Line #352 (CI ver. 2.2.2)

`$this->ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

to

`$this->ip_address = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

and its done.