# CodeIgniter cron job command line error

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line, cron

My hosting package (Cloud Next) actually includes scheduled tasks as standard with a testing facility and instructions for setting up a new task.

My question is whether or not I am using correct command line:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/index.php update home
```

My update script url is: http://www.mydomain.com/admin/update - however, I use subfolders for my controllers, therefore (with routing) my controller is found in ...application/controllers/admin/update.php so my controller is "update" and my method is "home".

Testing the above command line returns the following:

> "Your script returned the following: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.27
>
> Content-type: text/html
>
> welcome"

It's definitely NOT executing the script as required... The fact the word "welcome" is returned makes me think it's not factoring in the controller and method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/index.php admin update home
```

Comment: I'm not sure if my host is familiar with Codeigniter at all as their tech's suggestion was to point internally to the application's php file itself... They also mentioned about defining STDIN in the main index.php file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - try this

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/index.php admin update home
```

Not sure about the subfolder routing so try it with and without the admin, but the problem I had with it ignoring the call to the controllers and returning the default welcome message was fixed by using /usr/local/bin/php

Comment: I did come across this solution before - but when I test, it comes back with "Can't find 'user/local/bin/php'. Check location etc." @Andy Platt

Comment: Do you have SSH access? If so try doing 'locate bin/php' to see if the alternative php executable is somewhere else on the sever (your hosts equivalent of /usr/local/bin/php)

Comment: Just found someone with a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768231/run-cron-job-in-codeigniter-and-hostgator?rq=1) who solved it using wget and url to trigger a CI cron job.

Comment: This is a correct answer i changed /usr/bin/php to /usr/local/bin/php and the issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

> /usr/bin/php /home/sites/mydomain.com/public_html/index.php admin/update home

Enjoy!

You can read reference document about **Running via the CLI** from codeigniter [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html#how)